# Why isn't the confirm box working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Routes

```
  resources :listings do
 member do
   post :leadcreate
   post :storycreate
 end
```

end

Controller Action

```
  def destroy
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    @listing.destroy
    redirect_to 'root_path', :notice => "Listing Successfully Deleted"
  end
```

View

```
 <%= link_to "Delete", listing_path(@listing), :confirm => "Confirm Deletion", :method => :delete %>
```

Error

It just goes to "No Data Received" page and then when I refresh and go back to root the listing has actually been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 4, you should pass it as data attribute

```
link_to "Delete", listing_path(@listing), :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => 'Confirm Deletion'}
```

Documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)